# A special chemical compound with a touch of math

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, chemistry

What do you get when mixing

> Aluminium, Neon, Nitrogen, Sulfur, Titanium, Vanadium,

and two math ingredients

> $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\dfrac{1}{n})^n $ and (degree,?,seconds)

and

> don't ask why.

This mix exists only today! Find the mix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mix is

> **VALENTINE'S,** which is today!

The chemical elements and mathematical clues

> all resolve to single letters/symbols or bigrams: AL, NE, N, S, TI, V for the elements; E and ' (as in minute) for the math.

Then, we “mix” these ingredients by

> anagramming them to form a word or phrase that would make thematic sense. Of all the possible anagrams, VALENTINE'S is most appropriate here.

Comment: Note: I came up with this independently from @WeatherVane’s answer, but go upvote them as well!

Comment: @WeatherVane We do have different interpretations of the second mathematical element though, so it’s up to the OP to decide which one of us got it right :)

Comment: I could say there might be a better answer yet: things can always be better.... but don't dare to say that today.

Comment: Yeah, your interpretation of the second math symbol is correct, unfortunately the rework of my post did not highlight "and don't ask why", which is part of the question. I consider your answer as correct, I'm sure it is easy to complete and just cosmetic.I give credit to both of you.

Comment: I can see now where you get the rot13(ncbfgebcur) but I can't really see the relevance of the math expression (although I know what its value is).

Comment: @ThomasL Oh, if that was your intention, then I’ll make an edit to my edit to account for that.

Comment: @WeatherVane - right, the expression is a bit overdone, but I had no better idea how to integrate/explain this symbol.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood its mathematical value.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is

> **Valentines X**
>
>  The chemical symbols:
>  **Al** Aluminium
>  **Ne** Neon
>  **N** Nitrogen
>  **S** Sulfur
>  **Ti** Titanium
>  **V** Vanadium
>
>  and the mathematical symbols $e$ and $x$
>
>  make an anagram of **alnenstivex**
>
> ---
>
> The mathematical expression has the value $1$ and the missing word is **minute**
>  so perhaps that part means
>
>  **for one minute** ?
>
>  <sub>*love you* - only today!</sub>